# How can convert date into "dd/MM/yyyy" format?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter, nsdatepicker

In my app I am using date picker & show date in textfield,

Date picker given me a date in this format  "Mar 1, 2012"

I want that date in "dd/MM/yyyy" format.

how can i do that?

Comment: Please first do some googling before posting question here..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The date picker *displays* "Mar 1, 2012" but internally it stores the date as a `NSDate`, which you can convert to a `NSString` by using a `NSDateFormatter`, specifying the format you want:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *formattedDate = [df stringFromDate:yourDatePicker.date];
[df release];
```

The reference for the format string is here: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: You're welcome. As commented in your question, though, you could try a bit of googling before asking. General rule here: you're welcome to ask questions, but describe what you've tried, what doesn't work, and what you're expecting. Welcome to SO!

Comment: i tried with NSDateFormatter but my in my problem , i m not passing the DatePicker.date,get this problem . by the way Thanks, once again for solving this problem .

Comment: Hey Cyrille, How you set NSDatepicker display date format to "Mar 1, 2012". can you please describe me? In my case is display in "dd/MM/yyyy" format, but I want 'MM/dd/yyyy' date format to display date in NSDatePicker

Comment: You have no control over this. It's the language and locale defined by the user in their device settings that determines the presentation of date pickers through the whole OS.

Answer (score 4):

try the following code:

```
 NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mma"];
 NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
 NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
 [dateFormat release];
```